# Problem with NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone

i initialize instance variables in .h file,

NSInteger saveValue0, saveValue1, saveValue2, saveValue3;

NSMutableArray *nodeArray;

Now in .m file, in viewWillAppear event,

```
saveValue0 = 0; 
saveValue1 = 2; 
saveValue2 = 3;
saveValue3 = 0;

nodeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:saveValue0, saveValue1, saveValue2, saveValue3, nil];
```

But above variable does not inserted in the array. When i trying to see the objects in array using break point, it gives me 0 objects present in nodeArray. Why it will give me 0 objects. Any reason behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSInteger is not an object, and you can only store objects in arrays. Use [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] etc.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, this also generates a compiler warning: "warning: passing argument 1 of 'initWithObjects:' makes pointer from integer without a cast" I wonder why RRB didn't mention that?

Comment: @Mark Bessey, sorry and yes i forgetting to mention the warning message.

Comment: Thanks. There is not other way to execute my problem.

Comment: BTW @RRB, the reason you end up with no objects is that your first number was 0, which got cast to `nil`. That's the trigger for the end of the list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

NSInteger is just a standard C type.U cannot add those into NSMutableArray